# How to find rabbitmq setting for queue lenght limit value

Tags: rabbitmq

we use rabbitmq ,doc tell us how to setting Queue Length Limit .
but we haven't find Queue Length Limit default value .

has someone know that?

Answer (score 2):

By default, there is not a default value, 
You can use the command line tool to check the argouments:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues name arguments
Timeout: 60.0 seconds ...
Listing queues for vhost / ...
name    arguments
my_queue_limit  [{"x-max-length",5000}]
queue_no_limit  []
```

or the management UI[image]

as you can see `my_queue_limit` is set to 5000
`queue_no_limit` is without limits

Answer (score 1):

By default, rabbitmq queues are unbounded in nature i.e., they have no limit. But if you wish to impose some limit on the queue you can set it by using the `x-max-length` argument.